# Finding unique pairs in R (with no repetition of ANY values)

Tags: r, unique, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe containing blood results for 2 cohorts of patients (groups x and y). There are the same number of patients (with distinct id numbers) in each cohort (2000).
They have been (fuzzy) joined by the time of the test as I am interested in timings.
As there were many matches on test time, this has led to the ids being duplicated in both groups where timings are similar.

Here is an example:

```
id.x  time  value  id.y  time  value
1      23    4.1   11     18   4.3
1      23    4.1   12     25   4.8
2      54    3.9   13     51   4.3
2      54    3.9   14     52   4.0
3      72    4.5   14     70   4.3
3      72    4.5   15     25   4.3
```

There is a 1:1 ratio of id numbers in x and y groups.

## Attempts so far

I am trying to find **unique** pairs, where no id is repeated in either column. 
I have tried

```
test.df %>% distinct(id.x, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This half works - I get unique values from id.x, but they are matched with id.y values that are repeated, as I haven't specified that these also must be unique.

I have also tried

```
testsample.df <- unique(test.df[,c('icustay_id.x', 'icustay_id.y')])
```

This results in *unique pairs* i.e. each pair is not repeated, but each id is repeated many times in all possible combinations.

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

### Partial success

The closest I've come is a 2-stage process - subsampling with random unique id.y
then subsampling this with unique id.x using the following:

```
subsampled_data <- ddply(test.df,.(test.df$id.y), function(x) 
{x[sample(nrow(x),size=1),]})

subsampled_data2.df <- ddply(subsampled_data,.(subsampled_data$icustay_id.x), 
function(x) {x[sample(nrow(x),size=1),]})
```

Doing this, I successfully end up with unique pairs with only unique ids. However I lose quite a few rows, going from 2000, to ~1000.

Is it possible to find the unique pairs with unique ids without losing so many at each step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your expected output is. But hope this helps.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(id.x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), id.y = c(11,12,13,13,13,13))
```

Unique values of `id.x`:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df$id.x), ]

  id.x id.y
1    1   11
3    2   13
5    3   13
```

Now we still have duplicates in `id.y` and do

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df$id.y), ]
```

to remove them.

This leads to:

```
  id.x id.y
1    1   11
3    2   13
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% distinct(id.x, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% distinct(id.y, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

returns:

```
  id.x id.y
1    1   11
2    2   13
```

Comment: Thank you. Those methods do achieve unique pairs with unique values, but doing it in this step-wise fashion seems to lose even more data - I only ended up with 17 rows from ~2000!

I guess there is nothing in the first stage of the command to prevent a huge number of duplicated values in the id.y column.

If you then de-duplicate on the id.y column, you lose a lot of data.

I suppose that's where the ddply function in my question helps, selecting random rows. I'm not sure how `distinct` or `!duplicated` decides which rows to keep.

Comment: Hmm.. AFAIK `distinct` and `!duplicated` keep the first rows that match. I think the best you can do is to build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When we know what your expected output looks like and what kind of patterns we miss with my solutions then we might help you.